# What scope do flex actions execute in?

Tags: c, scope, compiler-construction, flex-lexer, lex

I'm learning to use flex and I've come up with a question for which I haven't found an answer (not even in the [reference](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Actions.html)). Suppose I have this code:

```
patt1   { do_foo(42); }
patt2   { do_bar(); }
```

This will probably work right. The problem is, `do_foo` might need to receive an argument by reference (say, an int) and do something (foo, actually) with it. The only way I can think of `do_foo` reaching that variable is by declaring it as a global variable, but depending on the scope that code runs there may be another (cleaner, better) solution.

Any ideas? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In effect, the generated scanner looks something like this, leaving out a lot of details mostly having to do with buffer management:

```
int yylex() {
  /* A bit of setup */
  while (1) {
    do {
      yy_current_state = next_state(yy_current_state, get_next_char());
    } while (has_no_action(yy_current_state));
    yy_act = yy_accept[yy_current_state];
    switch (yy_act) {
      case 1: /* First action block */
              break;
      case 2: /* Second action block */
              break;
      /* etc. */
    }
  }
}
```

So it's easy to see where the actions go, and the scope they are in. For that information to be useful, you need to see the hooks which can be inserted, so let's write that out again with some explicit hooks:

```
YY_DECL {
  /* Some declarations */

  /******** Prelude block *********/

  /* A bit of setup */
  while (1) {
    do {
      yy_current_state = next_state(yy_current_state, get_next_char());
    } while (has_no_action(yy_current_state));
    yy_act = yy_accept[yy_current_state];
    switch (yy_act) {
      case 1: YY_USER_ACTION   /**** User defined macro ****/
              /******** First action block *********/
              YY_BREAK
      case 2: YY_USER_ACTION
              /******** Second action block *********/
              YY_BREAK
      /* etc. */
    }
  }
}
```

One of the most interesting features is the "prelude block". In your (f)lex input file, it looks like this:

```
%option ...

%%
  /* Prelude block: indented lines before the first pattern */
  int locvar = 0;

patt1   { /* first action block */ }
patt2   { /* second action block */ }
```

The macros all have sensible defaults:

```
/* The default definition of YY_DECL will be different if you've
 * asked for a reentrant lexer
 */
#ifndef YY_DECL
extern int yylex(void);
#define YY_DECL int yylex(void);
#endif

/* Code executed at the beginning of each rule, after yytext and yyleng
 * have been set up.
 */
#ifndef YY_USER_ACTION
#define YY_USER_ACTION
#endif

/* Code executed at the end of each rule. */
#ifndef YY_BREAK
#define YY_BREAK break;
#endif
```

For your purposes, the most interesting of these is `YY_DECL`. If you want to pass arguments to `yylex`, you can modify the prototype by defining this macro. If you also need local variables during the `yylex` invocation, you can declare them in the prelude block. (This is more useful for "push" lexers, but it has its uses even for normal lexers.)

The `YY_USER_ACTION` and `YY_BREAK` macros are even more specialized. While they both look like they might be useful for debugging, you are generally much better off using flex's built-in trace facility. The `YY_USER_ACTION` macro is useful if you want to track column positions and not just line numbers; you can probably find examples of using it for this purpose. The `YY_BREAK` macro can be set to nothing (rather than `break`) for the case where your compiler complains about a `break` following a `return` statement.

Another macro, not indicated in the above code, is `YY_USER_INIT`, which will be incorporated in the one-time initialization code (also not shown above, sorry).

Most of these features are documented in the flex manual. `YY_DECL` is in [Section 9 ("The Generated Scanner")](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Generated-Scanner.html); `YY_USER_ACTION` and `YY_USER_INIT` are in [Section 13 ("Miscellaneous Macros")](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Misc-Macros.html) (along with some other features). (`YY_BREAK` is described at the very end of that section.)

The prelude block is a Posix feature, so it is available in `lex` as well, and is documented in Posix (as well as [Section 5.2 of the Flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Rules-Section.html)):

> Any such input (beginning with a `<blank>` or within `%{` and `%}` delimiter lines) appearing at the beginning of the Rules section before any rules are specified shall be written to `lex.yy.c` after the declarations of variables for the `yylex()` function and before the first line of code in `yylex()`. Thus, user variables local to `yylex()` can be declared here, as well as application code to execute upon entry to `yylex()`.

Comment: Thanks for your help and thorough explanation, I think that's just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

> What scope do flex actions execute in?

They execute in the scope of a giant `switch` statement in the `yylex()` function of the generated lexer.

> The problem is, do_foo might need to receive an argument by reference (say, an int) and do something (foo, actually) with it.

Might need to receive an argument from what? The only things that are running when an action is called are the parser and the lexer. Not your code. So you have no way of even passing an argument, let alone receiving it.

> The only way I can think of do_foo reaching that variable is by declaring it as a global variable, but depending on the scope that code runs there may be another (cleaner, better) solution.

There isn't. It maybe could be a `static` variable in the file scope of the generated lexer, which you can declare in the code section after the second `%%`, along with a getter and setter. But it can't be any kind of local variable in the `yylex()` method, because you don't have any control over when it gets called.

OR it can be stored in the `%union` of the parser, if that makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of declaring a global variable, you could create a macro. Since it's a preprocessing directive, it's probably "cleaner".

```
#define FOO 42

patt1   { do_foo(FOO); }
```

Comment: Not quite, actually. The fact is I need access to that variable in the main() too, after `do_foo` has modified it. Besides, a macro wouldn't serve the purpose of modifying its value.